# In what order RxJS operators can be used

Tags: typescript, rxjs

According this documentation https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/index.html there is main separation between Observable methods and Observable instance methods. I know that the Observable methods are called always before the Observable instance methods.Hope that this is true. But what is the order that we can use to combine/mix the Observable instance methods?

What I have as problem to solve is why the result from two similar Observables is not the same.

First one:

```
let getRequestJson = this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/users', new RequestOptions({params: this.params}))
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
console.log(getRequestJson);

let doThroughTheJsonData = getRequestJson.do(data => {
  this.count = data.count;
  this.loading = false;
  this.currentPage = page;
});
console.log(doThroughTheJsonData);

this.asyncUsers = doThroughTheJsonData.map(data => { 
  return data.user; 
});
console.log(this.asyncUsers);
```

Output:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: DoOperator}
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Second one:

```
this.params.page = page;
    let options = new RequestOptions({ params: this.params });

    let getRequest = this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/users', options);
    console.log(getRequest);
    let doThroughTheData = getRequest.do(data => {
        this.count = data.json().count;
        this.loading = false;
        this.currentPage = page;
      });
    console.log(doThroughTheData);
    this.asyncUsers = doThroughTheData.map((response: Response) => response.json().users);
    console.log(this.asyncUsers);
```

Output:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: CatchOperator}
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: DoOperator}
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

At the end what I receive in asyncUsers seems like different Observable although should be the same. 
In the first one I do 
 1. MAP over the data to transform the data in json format. 
 2. Then observable DO to fetch some data from the json data
 3. Again I use MAP to get only the users data from the json data.

In the second one I do
 1. first DO and inside I transfer the response data first to json and I get what I need
 2. then MAP transforming to json and get only the users data from the json data.

Is this problem Observable specific , is it related to the order of the methods map-do-map/do-map , or is clear typescript error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance of a Observable before you can call it's methods. To create an Observable you either are provided with one or you create one by using the static methods / constructor.

General Rx workflow:

- get some Observable (externally / static methods)
- transform the Observable (instance methods)
- `subscribe` to get the data out

**Getting a Observable**

```
var instance = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
```

gives you a stream of the values 1, 2 and 3.

```
var instance = new Rx.Observable(observer => { 
  /* do whatever you want with observer
     for example: */
  observer.next(1)
  observer.next(2)
  observer.next(3)
  observer.complete()
})
```

gives you an equally behaving Observable.

You can also get Observables externally: in your example `http.get` returns a Observable.

**Using/transforming the Observable**

After you created/retrieved an Observable, you can use whatever method on the Observable instance to transform the stream or it's contents.

For example:

```
var doubled = instance.map(x => x * 2)
```

that doubles everything inside. `instance` is not modified. You created a new Observable instance `doubled` which behaves the same, but with doubled values.

There are many operators. See http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html for the full list.

**Using the Observable**

This is where you extract the data from the Observable. This is where you would do side effects. You call `subscribe` and every time new data comes available your callback is called.

```
doubled.subscribe(x => view.x = x)
```

In your case:

```
var subscription = getRequestJson.subscribe(data => {
  this.count = data.count;
  this.loading = false;
  this.currentPage = page;
});
```

What you get out of calling `subscribe` is a object that you can use to let the source know you are no longer interested. `subscription.unsubscribe()` makes sure your callbacks are no longer called.

**Your sample**

You seem to log the Observable itself, not the values inside. View the Observable as a blueprint for how data will flow. Itself is not so interesting, whats interesting is whats inside. So use `subscribe` to get that data.

You use `.do(...)` for setting some values, don't do `do` ;). If you use `.do` all the time you might end up in a situation where actually nothing is done: you're never letting the source know that you are interested if you never call subscribe.

If you're using something like Angular, Angular might do the `subscribe`-call for you, but only if you hand off the Observable to Angular. If you let it dangle loose, no subscription is created.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I searched for so good link but without success. Yes I'm using Angular and that is why I'm using directly the observable in the page. What I understand is that the problem is not in the sequence of invoking the methods , and that there is not specific order when it comes only to the Observable instance methods. So I will search further inside the observables. Thank you.  I used the method DO because I needed part of the data that the Web Service returns , but the observable for the page in this case asyncUsers is only the users array. So i needed the data before array only